# Populate a map with an object / restructing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return a custom object in my map so I can construct a table with dynamic columns and rows.

I've got my datas :

```
 const cols = (p) => {
    <React.Fragment>
     <div>{p.username}</div>
     <div>{p.name}</div>
     <div>{p.surname}</div>
   </React.Fragment>
 }
```

Then my rows :

```
const rows = [
   { username : 'Kaherdin', name: 'Aurélien', suername : 'Everett'},
   { username : 'Babar', name: 'Stephane', suername : 'Gentil'}
]
```

And final my map :

```
{rows.map(row => {
   return cols(row)
  })}
```

Codesanbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/0ql6lp4z2p

Answer (score 3):

If you're not explicitly returning something you should use parenthesis instead of curly brackets.

```
const cols = (p) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div>{p.username}</div>
        <div>{p.name}</div>
        <div>{p.surname}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
 );
```

If you want to add more functionality you should use curly brackets with a `return` as [Tholle's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) example.

```
const cols = (p) => {

    //Extra functionality
    if(!p) return null;
    let myString = "String";


    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>{p.username}</div>
            <div>{p.name}</div>
            <div>{p.surname}</div>
            <div>{myString}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from your `cols` function. Add the `return` keyword and it will work as expected.

```
const cols = p => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{p.username}</div>
      <div>{p.name}</div>
      <div>{p.surname}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Using parentheses instead of brackets would have worked as well without the explicit `return`.